# ElasticBeanstalk, deployment error: Command hooks (directoryHooksExecutor.py --path /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/) failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

getting this error:

```
Command hooks (directoryHooksExecutor.py --path /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/) failed
```

after trying to deploy via git aws.push.

The deployment doesn't go through, the event that are thrown are:

> 2014-05-20 15:41:46 UTC-0700  ERROR   [Instance: i-808b90df Module:
>   AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance.
>   Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks
>   failed . 2014-05-20 15:41:43 UTC-0700 ERROR   Script
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed
>   with returncode 1

This is the error log:

```
2014-05-20 22:41:43,767 [ERROR] Command hooks (directoryHooksExecutor.py --path /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/) failed
2014-05-20 22:41:43,768 [DEBUG] Command hooks output: 
2014-05-20 22:41:43,768 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of Hook-PreAppDeploy: Command hooks failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 511, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 247, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 113, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command hooks failed
2014-05-20 22:41:43,795 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command hooks failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 122, in <module>
    worklog.build(detail.metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 117, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 502, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 511, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 247, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 113, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command hooks failed
2014-05-20 23:35:04,652 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
2014-05-20 23:35:04,653 [DEBUG] Describing resource AWSEBAutoScalingGroup in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:040951787496:stack/awseb-e-yz93miu6ma-stack/1bd7f720-da3f-11e3-a5f1-50fa003f9896
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I ran into similar issue on the bundle_install.sh, use

```
$> eb logs
```

and check your `/var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log`, for me it fails on installing gem 'forem'.

Comment: I am having a similar error but am having trouble identifying where the error is.  It is my first time reading the logs...can you give guidance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967427/error-on-first-git-aws-push-to-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 4):

I published to a dev environment beanstalk that had a typo in the web.config so none of the web site would even run with a web.config corruption error. This corrupted the EC2 instance behind my beanstalk's 1 instance environment beyond repair. I corrected the typo but only got this error message when publishing.

Tried restarting the beanstalk.
Tried restarting the EC2 instances behind the beanstalk.
I even tried restoring with an older but working version using restore application versions under: beanstalk/environment name/application versions.

None of these worked.

The Solution:

In EC2 management I terminated the EC2 instance behind the beanstalk. The beanstalk then automatically recreates a new EC2 instance. Once that was completed, I was able to once again publish without this error.

Comment: I followed your solution and it also worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! my issue was with the bad instance. Got it working with terminating the instance.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error: `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh failed with returncode 255`turns out it was composer the culprit.

The logs founds in `/var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log`:

```
2015-01-19 15:13:33,537 [INFO] (29969 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/    pre/10_composer_install.sh
+ '[' -f composer.json ']'
+ echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'
Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.
+ composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
Loading composer repositories with package information
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/    vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:975
#1 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(975): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL,     NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(853): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->    getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(818): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->    getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Applicat in phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/    symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 975
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/    symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:975
#1 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(975): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL,     NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(853): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->    getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(818): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->    getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Applicat in phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/vendor/    symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 975
2015-01-19 15:20:06,267 [ERROR] (29969 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-33] [root directoryHooksExecutor error] Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/    pre/10_composer_install.sh failed with returncode 255
```

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898) the ways to fix this is to increase the `memory_limit` in the php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar error. It appears that Elastic Beanstalk was unable to cope with a bad state on one of the instances, and simply couldn't deploy to it, causing a general instability in the EB environment.

I resolved it by decreasing the number of instances to 1, and redeploying. This kept only one good instance, killed the problematic one, and solved the issue.

Comment: Sounds like an ideal situation when you've got hundreds of production instances. Is EB a toy environment?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue i.e

> Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI

I would suggest to download and thoroughly check logs from Logs section of elastic beanstalk. Some where in that log you will find cause for the error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(o => o.HttpsPort = 443);
```

In Startup.cs of a .net core 5 app.

Basically you can't ask Elastic Beanstalk to do HTTP -> HTTPS redirection in your app. You have to go to EC2 dashboard and find the load balancer for your Elastic Beanstalk app. Then edit the Rules for the HTTP listener and don't forget to specify the HTTPS port.